# In magento 2 what is the correct way for getModel?

Tags: magento

i was make helloworld simple module in Magento 2 successfully.. Now i want to get Model data from the database...so please help me for getting model in Magento 2.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: yes.. i refer this link :  http://magento-quickies.alanstorm.com/post/66167788899/magento-2-replacements-for-getmodel-and

Comment: If it didn't work post what ever you tried and be specific in your question. Please go through http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking before asking question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is the steps for creating Model in Magento 2 Module:

1. Create `Question.php` in Model Folder For Question Model as follows:

   ```
   namespace Ecom\HelloWorld\Model;

   class Question extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
   {
   public function __construct(
           \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
           \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
           \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
           \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
           array $data = []
   ) {
       parent::__construct($context, $registry, $resource, $resourceCollection, $data);
   }

   public function _construct()
   {
       $this->_init('Ecom\HelloWorld\Model\ResourceModel\Question');
   }
   }
   ```
2. Create `Question.php` in ResourceModel Folder For Question Resource Model as follows:

   ```
   namespace Ecom\HelloWorld\Model\ResourceModel;

   class Question extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
   {
   public function _construct()
   {
       $this->_init('question_table_name', 'question_id');
   }
   }
   ```
3. Create `Collection.php` in ResourceModel/Question Folder For Question Collection Model as follows:

   ```
   namespace Ecom\HelloWorld\Model\ResourceModel\Question;

   class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
   {
   public function _construct()
   {
   $this->_init('Ecom\HelloWorld\Model\Question', 'Ecom\HelloWorld\Model\ResourceModel\Question');
   }
   }
   ```

Now you can call the Model in the following way:

```
$question = $this->_objectManager->create('Ecom\HelloWorld\Model\Question');
$question->setTitle('Simple Question');
$question->setDescription('Question Description');
$question->save();
```

**For Set Up Script:**

There are 2 different types of install scripts. A schema install and a data install. A schema install is used to install database structures like new tables, columns, relations. 
A data install or upgrade is used to add data to the database like a setting, page etc.

If Module is already created you need to craete 'UpgradeSchema.php' file in set up folder and add new database structure for update. If module is not installed you need to create 'InstallSchema.php' to add new database structure.

To simplify, in Magento 2 you can have 6 different Setup classes in your module:

```
    `Setup/InstallSchema` - Script that needs to run to create database schema when module installed
    `Setup/UpgradeSchema` - Script that needs to run to update or createdatabase schema when module upgraded 
    `Setup/InstallData` - Data Import when module installed
    `Setup/UpgradeData` - Data Import when module upgraded
    `Setup/Recurring` - Script run everytime when module upgrade
    `Setup/Uninstall` - Script run when Module uninstalled
```

There are no separate version setup files anymore, only one class per action.

After Making all changes you need to run the command: `php bin/magentosetup:upgrade`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.. but in phpmyadmin database can not created

Comment: In magento 1.x , database automatically create after calling config.xml file..  right? so in magento 2 how it is possible?

Comment: i used this command in my local cmd php bin/magento setup:upgrade .. after module upgrade ..magento will put the entry in setup_module table.. but my table is not created in phpmyadmin

Comment: Where is the $this->_objectManager  '_objectManager' defined in this line, i get Object of class Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager could not be converted to string.... this s my code

Comment: $sku='OUTIPCAM1';  $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();   $currentproduct=$this->$objectManager->create('Vendor\Module\Model\Queue');
  $currentproduct->setEntity_Id('1');
  $currentproduct->save();

Comment: Some older magento2 tutorials seem to use `Resource` instead of `ResourceModel`. Finally it makes sense. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I'm using Magento 2.1.6. When retrieving collection, I'm getting HTTP Error 500, the page just shows the block part, and the collection is not retrieved. My `getCollection` in Block file is `public function getCollection() { $model = $this->_objectManager->create('Softtama\HelloWorld\Model\HelloWorld');  $collection = $model->getCollection();  return $collection; }` and the code I used on my template is `<?php foreach ($this->getCollection() as $item) { ?> <li><small><b><?= $item->getLabel(); ?></b>: <?= $item->getValue(); ?></small></li> <?php } ?>`

Comment: Since Magento 2.1 the load and save functions of the model are flaged as deprecated.!!! Do not use this for new Plugins.