# Magento 2 - 503 (Service Unavailable) when creating a model

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento2, magento-2.0

I followed the instructions from the Accepted Answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31983546/in-magento-2-what-is-the-correct-way-for-getmodel/31984198) to create a model and model resource file.

Company/Project/Model/Album.php

```
<?php

namespace Company\Project\Model;

class Album extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel {

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    \Magento\Framework\Model\Resource\AbstractResource $resource = null,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
    array $data = []
    ) {
       $this->_logger = $logger;
       $this->_logger->addInfo("SO WE CAN ACTUALLY GET INTO THE MODEL FILE");
       parent::__construct($context, $registry, $resource, $resourceCollection, $data);
    }

  public function _construct() {
    $this->_init('Company\Project\Model\Resource\Album');
  }
}
```

Company/Project/Model/Resource/Album.php

```
<?php

namespace Company\Project\Model\Resource;

class Album extends \Magento\Framework\Model\Resource\Db\AbstractDb {
    public function _construct() {
    $this->_init('px_product_albums', 'id');
    }
}
```

Company/Project/Helper/Data.php - This is where I'm getting the error

```
<?php

class Data extend \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper {
    .....
    protected $pageFactory;

    public function __construct(
      ....
      \Magento\Cms\Model\PageFactory $pageFactory
    )
    ......

    function whereStuffIsHappening() {
    .....
      $albumId = WeHaveTheValue;
      $productId = WeHaveThisValueToo;
      $album = $this->pageFactory->create('Company\Project\Model\Album');
      $this->_logger->addInfo("Album code is alright");
      $album->setProductId($product->getId())->setPixleeAlbumId($albumId);
      $album->save();
      $this->_logger->addInfo("ALBUM ID SUCCESSFULLY SAVED");
```

It seems like the following line doesn't execute. I get a 503 (Service Unavailable).

$album = $this->pageFactory->create('Company\Project\Model\Album');

Some of the things that I have tried

- Flushing both Magento cache and cache storage
- I'm not developing on localhost. It's a magento.dev domain.
- Tried using objectManager directly, instead of pageFactory. [I read that using objectManager is a bad practice in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/32952/how-to-instantiate-a-model-in-magento2)

The strange thing is that I never see "SO WE CAN ACTUALLY GET INTO THE MODEL FILE" logged (Its a print statement in the Model file). Which leads me to think that the model is not being initiated. But I could be wrong.

Help?

Comment: Firstly, you shouldn't be using a PageFactory to create an instance of your model. It's a model, so it needs to either be instantiated via DI (constructor) or using the object manager. As for the link you've posted to, it's only bad practice if you instantiate the object manager directly. If you ask for the OM as a dependency as well, you can use it safely to create your models.

Comment: I actually tried instantiating it using the object manager. Like $this->_objectManager->create("..."). It gave the same error. Any other place that I should be looking at?

Comment: Was class PageFactory generated? It must located by path `var/generation/Magento/Cms/Model`