# Magento 2 - How to save data after the order was successfull in a custom table

Tags: php, magento, magento2

**First:** I understand how to create a custom module within a customtable in the backend. I had already done this and it works fine and I can save some information with it in the backend.
(Name: app/code/TestModule/Module)

But now I try to customize the order process.
I want to save some data, like the 'oder_id' and the 'order_date' in a custom table.

This process should work automatically after the order was successful.

**Problem:**
I don't understand how I can store this information in a custom table.

I have this in my **success.phtml** for checking the data in the frontend:

```
<?php 
$block->getOrderId()
$block->getShippingMethod() 
?>
```

The data is called with a function, here in my **Block/Onepage/Success.php**

```
...

public function getShippingMethod()
{
    return $this->_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder()->getShippingMethod();
}   

...
```

Well, and now I don't have any ideas for the next steps. For example, I saw this tut here [In magento 2 what is the correct way for getModel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31983546/in-magento-2-what-is-the-correct-way-for-getmodel/31984198) but it does not help me.

Other questions on stackoverflow answer only how to build a module or how to show order information.

I think i have to do something like this:

```
    $this->_Modulename->addData($data);
    $this->_transaction->save();
```

But after 3 days of reading, I try my luck here.
I don't need a final solution and I don't want a copy and paste of the answer code, I just won't understand how this "save data in the custom table after success" works.

I take everything from you guys because I am at the end of my knowledge.

TYIA

Comment: Have you looked at event observers in Magento? They're there exactly for this kind of problem - you can define a function to trigger when an order is saved and then operate on that order data in whatever way you see fit. In this case, you'd check just check if the order is new and if so, copy the necessary data into your custom table. Since you suggest that you need the order_id, you'll need to use the sales_order_save_after event. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/events-and-observers.html

Comment: Hi there, thank you for this information. Well, i understand what you mean but i dont know how i can use 'the sales_order_save_after event' in this way. Maybe you have some example for me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have it now.

Some functions like the "order-id" in:

app/code/Modules/Modulename/**Block/Onepage/Success.php**

```
<?php
namespace Modules\Modulename\Block\Onepage;

class Success extends \Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success
{
    public function getEntityId()
    {
       return $this->_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder()->getEntityId();
    }   
}
```

The following `save-function` is in one file: `app/code/Modules/Modulename/view/frontend/templates/succes.phtml`

```
// get order-id (the EntityId) ###
    $order_id = $block->getEntityId();

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
```

create connection DB

```
    $connection = $resource->getConnection();
```

Create query and fetch data from database:

```
    $tableName = $resource->getTableName('sales_order_item');
    $sql = "Select * FROM ". $tableName. " WHERE order_id =". $order_id;
    $result = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
```

And now we get them with a **foreach**. The "$n" is the count for all products and the "$productQty" is for each product qty.
**Example:**

ordered:

2 x red ball

1 x green bottle

So you have to count for all products (2 (bottle and ball)) and for each product qty (2x ball, 1x bottle). I hope it is clear what i mean ;)

```
    // do this for all products (in my case 2 times)
    $n = 0;
    foreach ($result as $allOptionkey) {

    $allOptionkey = array(unserialize($result[$n]['product_options']));
    $productTitle =  $result[$n]['name'];

        foreach ($allOptionkey as $keys) {
            $product = $keys['info_buyRequest'];
            $options = $keys['options'];

            $productKeyArray = array('0' => $product);

            foreach ($productKeyArray as $productKey => $productVar) {
              $productName = $productVar['product'];
              // get "product qty"
              $productQty = $productVar['qty'];
            }
        }
    $qn=0;
    $n++;
         // do this for each product qty (im my case 2x ball and 1 bottle)
        while($productQty > $qn) {
              $qncounter = $qn++;

              $tableModulename = $resource->getTableName('table_name');
              $sqlInsert = "Insert Into ".$tableModulename." (options,email) Values ( '".$productTitle."', '".$email."')";
             $connection->query($sqlInsert);
        }
    }
```

I build this "save-function" to save each ordered product in a custom table.