# Magento 2 insert data into database

Tags: magento, magento2

I recently created a module in Magento 2. Now I get the data from the database in front-end phtml file.The code is given below.

```
 try
{
    $question = $this->_objectManager->create('Magecomp\Firstmodule\Model\Firstmodule');
    $question->setTitle('SimpleQuestion');
    $question->save();
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
     echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

But I get following Error :

```
 Notice: Undefined property: Magecomp\FirstModule\Block\FirstModule::$_objectManager in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php.php on line 113
```

Please help me to get the object of model and then insert data into table.

Comment: Please follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31920769/how-to-save-data-using-model-in-magento2 , you will find your solution.

Comment: If you found solution using my reference link, should I post this as answer?

Comment: but it give me recoverable error :

Comment: Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Magecomp\Firstmodule\Controller\Index\Index::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\Model\Context

Comment: Can you edit the answer and place your controller's code over here.

Comment: place controller code in your question link  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31920769/how-to-save-data-using-model-in-magento2/32087745#32087745

Comment: i get the solution.. see the following my answer.

Comment: There was no need of any costruct function in controller. Glad you found the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my index action code in which i create a object of objectManagger and successfully add data into database using objectManager.

```
namespace Test\Firstmodule\Controller\Index;
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    public function execute()
   {
        $model = $this->_objectManager->create('Test\FirstModule\Model\Firstmodule');
        $model->setTitle('What is Question ?');
        $model->save();
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->getLayout()->initMessages();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
   }
}
```